# Trying to pass two data together

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass the 2 data(obj newQuarters, int newtworkKey) for post to backend site

component.ts

```
save = (x) => {
        this.filters.season = 1;
        if (!this.validation(this.newQuarters)) {
            this.seasonQuartersService.save(this.newQuarters).then(r => {
                        this.uiService.toast.success("Saved");
                    });
        }
    }
```

component.service.ts

```
save = (newQuarters) => {
    return this.$http.post(this.apiUrl + "save", { newQuarters: newQuarters});
}
```

Comment: Do you also have a question to this? And can you add more details? Where do you need to add that networkey? Maybe you can share more code?

Answer (score 2):

In a `POST` request you can technically send only one object, however you can encapsulate both these objects in one more object and send it to `POST` request

```
save = (newQuarters, networkKey) => {
    return this.$http.post(this.apiUrl + "save", { newQuarters: newQuarters, networkKey: networkKey});
}
```

and in component.ts:

```
save = (x) => {
        this.filters.season = 1;
        if (!this.validation(this.newQuarters)) {
            this.seasonQuartersService.save(this.newQuarters, this.networkKey).then(r => {
                        this.uiService.toast.success("Saved");
                    });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things I would advise to change in your structure.
I would advise using angulars http library.
It is quick and allows you to use observables, thus cleaning your code substantially (if you don't want to use Observables, consider using Promises).
Here is an example of how to create a post in Angular with HttpParams and a Request:

```
  save(saveType: SaveType,
       newQuarters: Object): Observable<SavedReplyType> {
    const url = this.apiUrl + 'save/'

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({,
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2100 00:00:00 GMT'
    });

    const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
      .set('save-type', saveType);

    return this.http
      .post<SavedReplyType>(url, newQuarters, {
        headers: headers,
        params: params,
        observe: 'body',
        responseType: 'json'
      })
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
      );
  }
```

The imports you would probably need:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to send data to server in a post method is using a Interface to send it.

```
export interface dataToSend
{
 id:number;
 name:string
}

let send: dataToSend = new dataToSend {id:4, name: 'test'};

return this.$http.post(this.apiUrl + "save", send);
```